# Carbon - Comparing two dates by their days

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

Recently I have tried to compare two dates by their days. e.g I want to check if the students have paid his/her fee in 5 of each month or not.

For more example, the student is registered in `2019-01-13` and now it is `2019-03-20` So I want to system notify me that the student fee time is passed 7 days. As well it should automatically check for next months.

Comment: show your code what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can define Task Scheduling

```
$schedule->command('student:fees_notify')->monthlyOn(5, '01:00');
```

You can schudele command based on your logic. it will triggered on 5th date on month start (01:00)

Your command will look something like

```
class StudentFeesNotify extends Command
{
   protected $signature = 'student:fees_notify';
   protected $description = 'your desc.....';

   public function handle()
   {
      // you can write your logic here
   }
}
```

Comment: Umm, It is a little different. Task Scheduling is a good solution when the registration dates are the same but here every student has its own registration date. To be clear let me draw the example.
For student A:
registration date: 2018-01-02
it should notify me on the 2nd day of each month. 

For student B:
registration date: 2017-11-16
it should notify me on the 16th day of each month.

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this

```
use Carbon\Carbon // don't forget to import carbon in your class

$days = 5;

// i would recommend to use chunk if you have a lot of records & limit this query t only people that might be subject to this alert
$students= Student::get();
$notifyList = [];

// assuming that the registration date column is created at and it's a valid date

$students->each(function($student) use (&$notifyList,$days){
  $notify = Carbon::parse($student->registration_date)->addDays($days)->lt(Carbon::now());
  if($notify){
   $notifyList[] = $student;
  }
});
```

The array will contain the users that surpassed their date

Comment: The code `$notify = Carbon::parse($student->registration_date)->addDays($days)->gt(Carbon::now());` returns true in any case. e.g the start date `2019-01-13` with adding five days it would be `2019-01-18` so it is always less than `now()` (2019-03-20).

Comment: I made a change, it should be lt not lg, so if the registration_date + 5 (ex : 2019-01-22) is less than today 2019-03-20 it means user still have time to pay, then after 5 more days, it will be (2019-01-18) & now will be 2019-03-27 which means user surpassed the 5 days period & should pay again (upon payment the field should be updated to next month), did i miss understand something ?